# Store random number in 2d array

Tags: c

I'm storing some random numbers into an 2d array, but some numbers appear to be on the side/border. I am not sure what's wrong with it. What I want is to have all the random numbers inside the border of the 2d array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 9
#define COL 9


void gameboard(char box[ROW][COL])
{
    int x,y;

    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y  <COL; y++)
        {
            box[x][y] =' '; 
        }   
    }
    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++)
    {
        box[0][x]='#';
        box[x][8]='#';

        box[x][0]='#';
        box[8][x]='#';   
    }    
 }


void rnum(char box[ROW][COL])
{
     int x,r1,r2,r3,r4;
     char r='1';
     srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); 

     for(x=0;x<9;x++)
     { 
        r1 =  rand()%9;
        r2 =  rand()%9;
        r3 =  rand()%9;
        r4 =  rand()%9;

        box[r1][r2]= r + x;
        box[r3][r4]= r + x;
     }     
}


int main(void)
{
    char box[ROW][COL];
    char name[20];
    int x,y,choice;

    gameboard(box);

    rnum(box);     

    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y  < COL; y++)
        {
         printf(" %c ",box[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    rnum(box);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Screen shot of output]

Comment: Take care of the boundaries. No element `0` or `8` should be overwritten because `#` signs are already there. Here's the for loop in rnum(): `     for(x=0;x<7;x++)
     { 
        r1 =  1 + rand()%7;
        r2 =  1 + rand()%7;
        r3 =  1 + rand()%7;
        r4 =  1 + rand()%7;

        box[r1][r2]= r + x;
        box[r3][r4]= r + x;
     }     `

Comment: Awesome! It works ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep the random numbers range between 1-9, you may use below function. But I don't know how many random numbers you are required to fill the block with, so that I leave it to you.

```
    void rnum(char box[ROW][COL]) {
      int x,r1,r2,r3,r4;
      char r='1';
      srand( (unsigned) time(NULL));
      int iter = 9;
      x = 0;
      while (iter != 0) {
        r1 =  rand()%9;
        r2 =  rand()%9;
        r3 =  rand()%9;
        r4 =  rand()%9;
        if (r1 == 0 || r2 == 0 || r1 == 8 || r2 == 8 ||
            r3 == 0 || r4 == 0 || r3 == 8 || r4 == 8)
          continue;
        else {
          box[r1][r2]= r + x;
          box[r3][r4]= r + x;
          iter--;
        }
        x++;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`rand() % 9` will return a number between `0` and `8` included. But your array's border occupies indices `0` and `8`.

To avoid overwriting it, pick a random number between `1` and `7`:

```
r1 = 1 + rand() % 7;
```

Note that scaling `rand()`'s output (dividing by `RAND_MAX + 1` then multiplying by your upper bound) has less bias than using a remainder, but in your case it's probably not important.

Comment: I changed it but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is here:

```
 for(x=0;x<9;x++)
 {
     r1 =  rand()%9;
     r2 =  rand()%9;
     r3 =  rand()%9;
     r4 =  rand()%9;

     box[r1][r2]= r + x;
     box[r3][r4]= r + x;
  }
```

Because r1,r2,r3,r4 are random numbers, and the border's coordinates are included in them. So it's normal that the numbers appear to be on the side/border.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of the boundaries. No element `[0]` or `[7]` should be overwritten because `#` characters are already there. The counter should also *by no means* exceed the array boundaries. Here's the `for loop` in `rnum()`:

```
for( x=0; x<7; x++) { 
    r1 = 1 + rand()%7; //always between 1 and 6 !
    r2 = 1 + rand()%7; 
    r3 = 1 + rand()%7; 
    r4 = 1 + rand()%7; 
    box[r1][r2] = r + x; 
    box[r3][r4] = r + x; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 9
#define COL 9

void gameboard(char box[ROW][COL]) {
    int x,y;
    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y  <COL; y++) {
            box[x][y] =' '; 
        }
    }
}

void rnum(char box[ROW][COL]) {
    int x,r1,r2,r3,r4;
    char r='1';
    srand( (unsigned) time(NULL)); 

    for(x=0;x<9;x++) {
        r1 =  rand()%9;
        r2 =  rand()%9;
        r3 =  rand()%9;
        r4 =  rand()%9;

        box[r1][r2]= r + x;
        box[r3][r4]= r + x;
    } 

    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++) {
        box[0][x]='#';
        box[x][8]='#';

        box[x][0]='#';
        box[8][x]='#';
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char box[ROW][COL];
    char name[20];
    int x,y,choice;

    gameboard(box);

    rnum(box);     

    for(x = 0; x < ROW; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y  < COL; y++) {
            printf(" %c ",box[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    rnum(box);

    return 0;
}
```